# Background video not playing when App is loaded for the first time in Angular 5 App

Tags: html, jquery, angular, typescript, html5-video

I am trying to keep a video as the background of my Angular 5 app. But, when the page is loaded for the first time, the video is not playing.But If i go to any other page, and then again come back to home page, then the video is playing.

Till now i have tried these all

1.

```
<video id="v-control" width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" tabindex="0">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/img/MyVideo.mp4" alt=" MyVideo" />
   <source type="video/webm" src="assets/img/MyVideo.webm"  alt=" MyVideo" />
</video>
```

2.
[Jquery plugin for background video](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Responsive-Full-Page-Video-Background-Plugin-with-jQuery-Vide.html)

```
<div data-vide-bg="MyVideo">
  <video id="v-control" width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" tabindex="0">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/img/MyVideo.mp4" alt=" MyVideo" />
    <source type="video/webm" src="assets/img/MyVideo.webm"  alt=" MyVideo" />
  </video>
</div>
```

and included

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.vide.js"></script>
```

in index.html

Still i am facing the same issue. Can anyone help , where am i doing wrong?

Comment: which browser? and what is the size of the video? If the Internet slow means, it will take sometime download and show

Comment: @AravindS video is playing on mozilla, safari but not on chrome. Video size is 750KB. I am having a decent internet speed. I am still not able to figureout where i went wrong

Comment: any console error in chrome? try this site http://www.warnermusicnashville.com/ its in angular and have a header video.

Comment: No console error. and thanks for the url, i will try and let you know

Comment: url not useful @AravindS

Comment: sorry for that..can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856562/chrome-android-video-autoplay-inside-angular-2-component

Answer (score 4):

Try using `onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true"` within `video` tag as below, Hope this helps:

```
<video onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" autoplay loop  preload="auto">
    <source src="Video_url" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me **Ionic 5+ / Angular 12+**

*.html*

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="auto" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
  <source [src]="video" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

*.ts*

```
video = 'assets/videos/background-video.mp4';
```

**Important note:** You must use around `1 MB` video here. If it'll have around `5 MB` then it won't work on the web.