# HTML5 video doesn't autoplay (even while muted) in Chrome 67 using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser, html5-video

I know several posts have similar issues, but none of the ones I have looked at have the specific issue I'm experiencing.

The problem is, I have a HTML5 video which won't autoplay, even though it is muted. Specifically, it doesn't work in Chrome. It works completely fine in Safari and Firefox.

The code snippet looks as such:

```
<video class="landing-page-video" poster="assets/images/video-poster.jpg" loop muted playsinline preload="metadata" disableRemotePlayback>
    <source src="assets/images/landing-page-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support video.
</video>
```

The code snippet is from this [website](https://student-talks.com) and it is built with Angular. I've removed attributes that are only related to Angular in the copied snippet for clarity.

I have tried several combinations of what is suggested various places online, as well as carefully reading the documentation for the newer versions of Chrome that affect the autoplay feature. I am, however, at a loss, with nothing seeming to work.

Supposedly, the policy change should only affect autoplay for videos with audio, but it still seems to block autoplay for this muted video.

One weird behavior that I have noticed is, that sometimes the video will start playing if I open the chrome inspector tool and close it again. Not always, though.

I also tried triggering the `play()` directly through JavaScript, but this of course won't work since the user didn't initiate it through a click.

Could this be a bug with Chrome or is it on my end? Any help is appreciated!

---

**EDIT: Still not working. I have tried the following, with no result:**

- Using the `http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4` video as source instead.
- Adding `autoplay` attribute.
- Replacing the whole `<video>` element with the one from the suggested [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/2cz6f53k/).

When I enable `controls`, the audio button shows as grayed out "sound on" version, might be due to my video having no audiotrack. However, when using the demo video, it still shows the audio button with "sound on" in spite of the `muted` attribute being set.

---

**EDIT 2: Added code for the Angular component which contains the video element:**

HTML:

```
<video class="landing-page-video noselect"  poster="assets/images/video-poster.jpg" *showItSizes="{min:900}" muted loop autoplay disableRemotePlayback>
    <source src="assets/images/landing-page-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support video.
</video>

<div class="landing-page-video-overlay noselect" *showItSizes="{min:900}" [ngStyle]="{'height': videoHeight + 'px'}">
    <st-svg-logo class="video-overlay-logo"></st-svg-logo>
</div>
<div class="noselect" *showItSizes="{max:899}" style="position: relative; top: 0; height: 100vh;">
    <img src="assets/images/landing_pic_mobile_3.jpg" alt="Student Talks in Space" class="landing-page-video"
         style="height: 100vh;">
    <img class="video-overlay-logo" src="assets/images/student-talks-header.png"/>
    <img src="assets/images/landing_pic_mobile_bottom.png" class="bottom-transition-glitch" alt="">
</div>


<div class="st-container">
    <st-events-list class="full-width event-list" *showItSizes="{max:899}"></st-events-list>
    <h1>HOW IT WORKS</h1>
    <st-what-is class="st-row"></st-what-is>
    <st-world-map class="full-width" *showItSizes="{min:899}"></st-world-map>
    <st-counters #counters class="full-width" stInView (cameInView)="counters.countUp()"></st-counters>
    <st-events-list class="full-width" *showItSizes="{min:900}"></st-events-list>
    <br><br>
    <st-video class="st-row"></st-video>
    <br><br>
    <st-partners></st-partners>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.landing-page-video, .landing-page-video-overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width:100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.landing-page-video-overlay {
  height: 56.25vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 899px) {
  .video-overlay-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    right: 21%;
    width: 100vw;
    animation: fade-in 1s;
    z-index: 160;
  }

}
```

TypeScript:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'st-home',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to expose it to click and add controls?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually noticed, that the audio control button is grayed out when I enable the controls, and it has the appearance of being "not muted". Could it be because the video file has no audio, therefore it cannot be muted?

Comment: Interesting case. Then it could be possibly bug of Chrome. You can check that simply by replacing your video file with the one with sound..

Comment: I just did that + a few more things, see the edit at the bottom of the post. I hope it is not a chrome bug, but instead me overlooking something!

Comment: Can you share angular code that prints that element?

Comment: Added in a 2nd edit to the post!

Comment: Note that if you append video tag into DOM, it must be already with all these attributes because browser checks that onload. So if angular somehow hides these attrs, it could brake it. Just for curiosity try to add `*ngIf="true"` into video tag..

Comment: Ok, do you have any links for how Angular does this? It would be worth investigating... I tried the `*ngIf="true"`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: I thought so. It was from [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856562/chrome-android-video-autoplay-inside-angular-2-component?rq=1). I know only AngularJS. Not angular. So if this is related to Angular behaviour, I cant help..

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at it. Thanks for the help so far, I'll have to figure out if it is related to Angular, and if so find a workaround.

Comment: You can find out if you put that video tag static into fiddle or local page..without Angular..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution to Angular 2+ of cases in which automatic reproduction is needed silent and does not work.**

1. Autoplay is prevented, until the user performs an action on the screen. *Chrome's autoplay policies will change in April of 2018.* [https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes]
2. Autoplay works when the "mute" attribute is selected.
3. For this case, in which we want to use the attribute "mute" and it does not work, the problem is Angular.

> > The same thing happened to me and after hours of searching. And I found the following.
> >        - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686550/10435550][2]

`onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"`

> > This is the key. Angular can not translate the attibute "mute" correctly. For this reason you have to use the "onloadedmetadata".

**Conclusion**

Tested and running with angular 5.2 in Chrome 69 and IE 11.

```
<video onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" autoplay>
    <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I LOVE YOU. for the record for anyone else I needed to use both of these `oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"`

Comment: Your comment about angular not translating the attribute "muted" made me think. When I use `[muted]="'muted'"` it works as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I needed both `oncanplay` and `oloadedmetadata`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using the HTML attribute `autoplay` & `muted`.
You need to use the Angular attributes `[autoplay]="true"` & `[muted]="true"`

Comment: That has fixed my issue, particularly with angular 8.

Comment: Thanks. This has fixed my issue in angular 8

Answer (score 8):

I needed to use both `onloadedmetadata` and `oncanplay` to fix in angular 6

```
<video loop muted autoplay oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Angular 6.
I wanted a muted autoplay.
None of the previous worked for me, this one did:

```
oncanplay="this.play()"
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: for the record i needed to also use `onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"` but the combination worked

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to bigless' linking [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856562/chrome-android-video-autoplay-inside-angular-2-component?rq=1) I solved the problem.

MY implementation of the solution from the link looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-chrome-fix" [innerHTML]="videoTag"></div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'st-home',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent {

  videoTag;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.videoTag = this.getVideoTag();
  }

  private getVideoTag() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
        `<video class="landing-page-video noselect" muted loop autoplay playsinline disableRemotePlayback>
            <source src="assets/images/landing-page-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>`
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE: I had to move the class** `landing-page-video` **into the global** `styles.css` **file, since angular does not append the component specific prefix (ie. it won't apply the styling if it is placed in the component-specific css file)**

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me in chrome 67 (and firefox 61).

```
<video width="320" height="240" muted controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

live example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/2cz6f53k/)

hope this helps.

Comment: I see the fiddle working, but same code applied to the website still won't work. Perhaps it could be due to the reason stated as a reply to bigless?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `autoplay` attribute in `<video>` tag.

```
<video autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The autoplay attribute applied to the website still doesn't work. Perhaps it could be due to the reason stated as a reply to bigless?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example:

```
<video [muted]="'muted'" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline id="video-start">
    <!-- Dynamic Content -->
    <source *ngIf="backgroundVideo?.Link?.Url" [src]="backgroundVideo.Link.Url" type="video/mp4">

    <!-- Default Content, displaying when dynamic content has a problem -->
    <source [src]="baseURL + '/SiteAssets/assets/videos/film_kpmg_home.mp4'" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Be careful about that, if you write only muted="muted" instead of [muted]="'muted'", autoplay could not work fine in an angular project.

And, for autoplay property, you need also to use 'playsinline' attribute for only mobile browsers. It makes no difference for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with angular 6 and Chrome 70, the [new autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) was changing by google in the last months, I solve the problem adding a new method in to the ngAfterViewInit()

```
<!-- home.component.html -->
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video #homeVideo id="homeVideo" class="fullscreen-bg__video" muted loop autoplay disableRemotePlayback onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" *ngIf="true">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>

// home.component.ts
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let myVideo = document.getElementById('homeVideo') as HTMLFormElement;
  myVideo.muted = false;
  myVideo.loop = true;

  if (myVideo){
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Play ?", myVideo.play() );
      myVideo.play();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but sometimes muted attribute won't completely mute the video. What I often experienced was it's volume 1 instead of 0 still, and 100% volume doesn't mean it's muted. So when I set volume to 0 it worked.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp