# Get native html videos to autoplay on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

In our website [coverr.co](https://coverr.co) we offer free stock videos for any commercial use.

One of the coolest things in Coverr is allowing our users to see the video running as a background video in our site. As an example: https://coverr.co/videos/Beach

If you'll access this page using FF or Safari the video will autoplay, no problem. However since [Chrome's latest policy change](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) on April 2018, autoplay has been inconsistant on Chrome.

We've added the "autoplay" and "muted" flags (although all of our video footage is sound-less), as required by the new spec, but with no luck. It would sometimes play and sometimes just stay frozen until the user actively start playback.

Can someone please help us solve this mystery?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there no way to trigger play by Javascript (_eg:_ when page load "complete" event, now find `<video>` element and give it a ".play" command)?

Comment: So, there is:
    var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}

but it doesn't make sure that the video plays, you might get and error even though everything is legit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, and it was related to the fact we've used angular 2.

Apparently Angular 2 has a problem to add the `muted` meta tag properly.
The full answer [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574513/690866), but basically you need to use Angular's `onloadedmetadata` attribute:

```
onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"
```

and in general, this is how it should look like:

```
<video onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" autoplay>
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Important comment:

We've also added `oncanplay="this.play()"` for additional playback robustness.
So in the future we can handle play() promise and show play button if autoplay was rejected by some another reason

Additional important comment:

Following [@VC.One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057709/vc-one)'s question, just wanted to clarify that there is a way to **verify or at least get notified of playback** (taken from the article in my question):

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();
if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```

but it doesn't make sure that the video *actually* plays, and so you might get and error even though everything is legit. And of course, adding a play button can work, but it really takes out the "sting" of what we're trying to do - autoplay a muted video in the site's background.

Basically all you need it to have both autoplay and muted injected properly, and apparently in Angular 2 it's not such a trivial task...

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Cannot reproduce your issue (on Chrome version 69.0.3497.100):

This autoplays and loops correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="100%"  autoplay loop>
<source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

**(2)** Your cover/poster image is blocking the video (which may be playing underneath).

Try removing the cover image. Your frozen frame (not playing) is actually the poster image. Test by removing cover image code (*eg:* `<div class="poster hidden">` and related).

PS: If you right click poster image and choose "show controls", the displayed "play" button will start playback.