# how to fix "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() "

Tags: javascript, dom, angular5, html5-video

I am trying to autoplay video background in html5,css,angular5- Randomly its working and not working.

So I tried to include code in angular that to play when it is loading the page.It's throwing -Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play()

I tried checked stackoverflow same error like this.I have applied those solution in multiple way to fix the issue. Still throwing error.

```
    component
    =========
    @ViewChild('videoPlay') videoplay: ElementRef;
    videopl: HTMLVideoElement;

    //first i tried this. Still throwing error
    this.videoplay.nativeElement.play();

    //second i tried this still throwing error.
    const playPromise = this.videoplay.nativeElement.play();
    if (playPromise !== null){
     playPromise.catch(() => { this.videoplay.nativeElement.play(); })
    }

    //third i tried this still throwing error.
    this.videopl=this.videoplayer.nativeElement;
    this.videopl.play();


    html part
    =========
    <!--first try-->
    <video id="videoid" autoplay muted loop  preload
     poster="img.png"  #videoPlayer>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>

     <!--second try-->
     <video id="videoid" autoplay="true" muted="muted" loop  preload 
       poster="img.png"  #videoPlayer>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>


    <!--third try-->
    <video id="videoid" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop  preload
     poster="img.png"  #videoPlayer>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

Need to play video automatically without any error.

Comment: do `console.log(this.videoplay.nativeElement)` and what it returns?

Comment: I got this error yesterday only. But I was getting this error because my video was not existing at the location I had mentioned. Can you please try this video tag

<video id="videoid" autoplay muted loop  preload poster="img.png"  #videoElement>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
   
    </video>   No component code required

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina-thank you for you reply. I tried it prints the video tag as such .I forgot to mention one more thing for first time with any video from the beginning it works. After refresh its not working it shows the poster image.That why i was trying to play the video through the code.Still i am having the same results.Please any other suggestion. Nandita Sharma- Thank you for you reply i tried different video's including your link also still not working. Please any other suggestions.

Comment: Some how i have to play the video automatically.Please any help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me to autoplay is here=>https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980364/5755872

```
 <video id="videoid" autoplay muted loop  preload
 poster="img.png"  oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
 <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Only I need is to autoplay my video.so I am removed all the lines in component for play function.

“Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() ”-this issue i didn't find any solutions. But i will try to find the solution for this error also.

Thank you for reading this issue.